# Consistency of kafka consumer endOffsets

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have kafka topic with replication factor 3 and `min.insync.replicas = 2`, a producer that sends X messages to this topic with `acks=all`.
After a while (within 1 min) after all messages sent to the topic new consumer is created for this topic using java kafka client. Using `consumer.endOffsets()` method end offsets of all kafka partitions for this topic are fetched. Another invocation of the same method `consumer.endOffsets` sometimes return different end offsets for some partitions.

In this setup there are no new messages sent to kafka topic after the creation of the consumer.

According to java docs of `endOffsets`:

```
/**
     * Get the last offset for the given partitions.  The last offset of a partition is the offset of the upcoming
     * message, i.e. the offset of the last available message + 1.  If messages have never been written
     * to the the partition, the offset returned will be 0.
     *
     * <p>
     * This method does not change the current consumer position of the partitions.
     * <p>
     * When {@code isolation.level=read_committed} the last offset will be the Last Stable Offset (LSO).
     * This is the offset of the first message with an open transaction. The LSO moves forward as transactions
     * are completed.
     *
     * @see #seekToEnd(Collection)
     *
     * @param partitions the partitions to get the end offsets.
     * @return The end offsets for the given partitions.
     * @throws org.apache.kafka.common.errors.AuthenticationException if authentication fails. See the exception for more details
     * @throws org.apache.kafka.common.errors.AuthorizationException if not authorized to the topic(s). See the exception for more details
     * @throws org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException if the offsets could not be fetched before
     *         expiration of the configured {@code request.timeout.ms}
     */
    @Override
    public Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

endOffsets returns Last Stable Offset (LSO) which acknowledges by all replicas.

How come that sometimes (not very often) end offsets changing between subsequent invocation of this method? 
Is it expected behavior that endOffsets are eventually consistent? A Bug?