# Kafka seekToEnd is not moving the pointer to the end of the topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a consumer that connects to the Kafka topics, Every Kafka topic has 1 partition. I am moving the Kafka pointer based on a consuming strategy. For the `LATEST` strategy same is done following way:

Retrieve end offsets:

```
Map<TopicPartition, Long> topicEndOffsets = consumer.endOffsets(partitions) 
logger.debug(); // log endoffset for every topic
```

Once logging is done, I move the topic offset to the end using `seekToEnd` API method.

I have 5 topics, this logic is working fine for all the topics except 1 of the topic, 1 topic returns the incorrect offset in an alternate run of the test case. The weird thing is Kafka always returns the value the same incorrect value (assume 798).

Some more observations and trials and errors I did:

- Assume the current end offset is at 1000, a producer produces 2 messages. a consumer consumes these two messages. offset moves to 1002. Now I re-run the consumer test case, again Kafka endOffset() returns 798.
- In alternate incorrect end offset value(798). `seekToEnd()` moves the pointer to 798 instead of 1002.
- `consumer#position()` API returns address as 1002 and as end offset is behind at 798. I tried to move offset by calling `seek(1002)` API but instead, Kafka moved end offset pointer to 798.

I am using Kafka client version 2.0.1. I could reproduce the behavior with version 2.3.0 also.

I could see another question describing the same behavior. [Consistency of kafka consumer endOffsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914192/consistency-of-kafka-consumer-endoffsets)

As this behavior is reoccurring only for 1 out of 5 topics, is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Can you check if 798 happen to be the earliest offset available in this 'bad' TopicPartition?

Comment: @mazaneicha No, it's not. But if it was how does it affect?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7703. Since you mentioned version 2.0.1 I assumed your broker is 2.0 also.